# FOSS DNS Server with API?

Tags: domain-name-system

Evaluating alternatives to BIND for internal DNS. Would love to integrate DNS into the automated provisioning process using an API. Does anyone know of a FOSS DNS server alternative to BIND that has a API to boot? I use to use MyDNS which performed great but rather not edit the DB directly if a better solution is already out there.

Comment: You can do dynamic DNS updates with Bind, including even automatic DNSSEC.

Comment: Can you explain why it is you don't want to use BIND?

Comment: BIND has a horrible security track record, even after the rewrite. Although, if there is a restful API and possibly a good up-to-date webui then I'd reconsider!

Comment: @CarpeNoctem: you should make that clear in your question so that others can direct you to other DNS servers with security in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tried any of them but there are some FOSS API around for PowerDNS.

http://doc.powerdns.com/

http://kennethkalmer.github.com/powerdns-on-rails/

https://github.com/devel/PowerDNS-API#readme

http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/PowerDNS-API-Client/PowerDNS/API/Client/Request.html

Comment: Thanks, going to test both APIs and will update question with any relevant findings.

Comment: @CarpeNoctem do you have any findings?